# Showing JSON data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I cant show the JSON response to the HTML, all I am getting is `his.state.selectedData.map is not a function`.

This is the payload

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name":"john",
    "age" : 22
}
```

This is in the constructor

```
this.state = {
selectedData : [] 
}
```

This is the HTTP request:

```
axios.post("/api/data", data)
          .then(res =>{
             console.log(res)
             this.setState({
                selectedData : res.data
             })

          })
```

And this is how I am trying to show the result

```
 <div>
  <ul>
    { this.state.selectedData.map(data => {
      <li>{data.name}</li>
    })}
  </ul>
  </div>
```

what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Does `res.data` look like the object in your first snippet? That is not an array, so trying to use `map` on that object will give rise to your error. Maybe you want to write `this.setState({ selectedData: [res.data] });`?

Comment: Yes, that is it looks like, with `[res.data]` it does not work either

Comment: Do you get the same error with `[res.data]`? Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it will be easier to say what might be wrong.

Comment: with `[res.data]` i have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
`

Comment: That sounds very odd. Please create a working example and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from api is json object and your are trying to use map in json object will not work. Change selectedData to json object like below in the constructor

```
this.state = {
selectedData : {} 
}
```

And in the code you can directly refer the name key like below and remove the map.

**`this.state.selectedData.name && <li>{this.state.selectedData.name}</li>`**

Comment: Thanks , how would it be if the payload a json array was.?? 

`palyload = [{
}]`

maybe then we can use `map ` ?

Answer (score 2):

Initially `selectedData` is array after the ajax you changing it to object. So map function is not going work.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        selectedData :[]
     }
   }

readJson(json){
    let output=[]
    Object.keys(json).forEach(key=>{
        output.push(
            <li>{json[key]}</li>
        )
    });

    return output;
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.readJson({ "id": 1,"name":"john","age" : 22 })}</ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you want to keep your state object as an array.

```
let newData = this.state.selectedData;
axios.post("/api/data", data)
      .then(res =>{
         console.log(res)
         newData.push(res.data)
         this.setState({
            selectedData : newData
         })

      })
```

Comment: One thing the raises my left eye brow is why this is a post request? You are getting data from your api? That sure sounds like a get request.

Comment: I am Posting data to a server and using server's response. Indeed a Post request in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```js
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  loadedList: [],
  lists: [],
};
  }

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/../static/data/terrifdata.json')
      .then(response => {
       this.setState({
         lists: response.data,
         loadedList: response.data,
         isLoading: false
        })
    })
 }

<div>
{loadedList.map((postDetail, index) => {
                    return (
                  <h5>
                     {postDetail.name}
                  </h5>
                  )}
               }
</div>
```